# JavaScript onLoad function + IE = problems

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jstl

I'm working on a school project which should give students the ability to search institutes and extra information about them.

After the search the results are displayed like this: can't show image, have to get a rep of 10, I'll do this later.

This works, I use this onLoad function:

```
function onLoad() {  
    for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("tr").length; i++) {  
        if(document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i].id.length != 0) {  
            document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i].style.visibility = "collapse";  
        }  
    }  
}
```

but when I use IE7 I first only get a few institutes (normally 19)
Then I press on one of the plus signs which hold this function:

```
function uitvouwen(trId,imgId) {
var url = document.getElementById(imgId).src;
if (url.indexOf("Images/plus.gif") != -1) {
    for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("tr").length; i++) {
        if(document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i].id == trId) {
            document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i].style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }
    url = "Images/minus.gif";
} else if(url.indexOf("Images/plusbottom.gif") != -1) {
    for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("tr").length; i++) {
        if(document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i].id == trId) {
            document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i].style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }
    url = "Images/minusbottom.gif";
} else if (url.indexOf("Images/minus.gif") != -1) {
    for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("tr").length; i++) {
        if(document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i].id == trId) {
            document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i].style.visibility = "collapse";
        }
    }
    url = "Images/plus.gif";
} else if(url.indexOf("Images/minusbottom.gif") != -1) {
    for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("tr").length; i++) {
        if(document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i].id == trId) {
            document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i].style.visibility = "collapse";
        }
    }
    url = "Images/plusbottom.gif";
}
document.getElementById(imgId).src = url;
```

}

Weird enough all 19 results get displayed now

So my question is:

Does IE7 stop my onLoad code (maybe because it's too much to handle) or do I have to look for errors in my program?
On other browsers this program works perfectly..

This is the code actual HTML, JSTL and JavaScript code (I know it's messy but it's an exercise on JSTL so i need to use it):

```
<c:forEach var="instituut" items="${ requestScope.instituten}">
<table id="LijstResultaten<%= i %>" summary="LijstResultaten<%= i %>">
    <%
        i++;
        if (instituten.size() != i) {
    %>
    <c:set var="urlLijn" scope="session" value="Images/line.gif"/>
    <c:set var="urlMin" scope="session" value="Images/minus.gif"/>
    <c:set var="urlPlus" scope="session" value="Images/plus.gif"/>
    <c:set var="urlLijnLong" scope="session" value="Images/linelong.gif"/>
    <% } else {
    %>
    <c:set var="urlLijn" scope="session" value="Images/empty.gif"/>
    <c:set var="urlMin" scope="session" value="Images/minusbottom.gif"/>
    <c:set var="urlPlus" scope="session" value="Images/plusbottom.gif"/>
    <c:set var="urlLijnLong" scope="session" value="Images/empty.gif"/>
    <% }
    %>
    <tr>
        <td><img alt="" id="instituut<%= i %>" name="instituut<%= i %>" src="${ urlPlus}" onclick="uitvouwen('MeerInfoInstituut<%= i %>','instituut<%= i %>')" onmouseover="cursorVeranderen()" style="cursor: pointer;"/></td>
        <td colspan="4">${instituut.name}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="MeerInfoInstituut<%= i %>">
        <td><img alt="" name="lijn" src="${ urlLijn}" onclick="init();"/></td>
        <td><img alt="" name="join" src="Images/join.gif"/></td>
        <td colspan="2">Land:</td>
        <td><%= landen.get(i - 1).getName() %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="MeerInfoInstituut<%= i %>">
        <td><img alt="" name="lijn" src="${ urlLijn}"/></td>
        <td><img alt="" name="join" src="Images/join.gif"/></td>
        <td colspan="2">Stad:</td>
        <td>${ instituut.city }</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="MeerInfoInstituut<%= i %>">
        <td><img alt="" name="lijn" src="${ urlLijn}"/></td>
        <td><img alt="" name="join" src="Images/join.gif"/></td>
        <td colspan="2">Postcode:</td>
        <td>${ instituut.zipcode }</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="MeerInfoInstituut<%= i %>">
        <td><img alt="" name="lijn" src="${  urlLijn }"/></td>
        <td><img alt="" name="join" src="Images/join.gif"/></td>
        <td colspan="2">Straat:</td>
        <td>${instituut.street}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="MeerInfoInstituut<%= i %>">
        <td><img alt="" name="lijn" src="${  urlLijn }"/></td>
        <td><img alt="" name="join" src="Images/join.gif"/></td>
        <td colspan="2">Website:</td>
        <td>
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${  instituut.website == 'Onbekend' }">
                    ${ instituut.website }
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    <a href="http://${ instituut.website }" >${ instituut.website }</a>
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <%
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Outgoing_student>> studentlijst = (ArrayList<ArrayList<Outgoing_student>>) request.getAttribute("studentlijst");
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Outgoing_teacher>> docentlijst = (ArrayList<ArrayList<Outgoing_teacher>>) request.getAttribute("docentlijst");

        int aantalStudenten = studentlijst.get(i - 1).size();
        int aantalDocenten = docentlijst.get(i - 1).size();

        String resultaatStudentnamen = "";
        String resultaatDocentnamen = "";

        int j = 0;
        for (Outgoing_student studentNamen : studentlijst.get(i - 1)) {
            resultaatStudentnamen += "<tr id=\"MeerInfoStudenten" + i + "\">\n";
            resultaatStudentnamen += "\t\t\t\t\t\t<td><img alt=\"\" name=\"lijn\" src=\"" + (instituten.size() != i ? "Images/line.gif" : "Images/empty.gif") + "\"/></td>\n";
            resultaatStudentnamen += "\t\t\t\t\t\t<td><img alt=\"\" name=\"lijn\" src=\"Images/line.gif\"/></td>\n";
            resultaatStudentnamen += "\t\t\t\t\t\t<td><img alt=\"\" name=\"join\" src=\"" + (studentlijst.get(i - 1).size() != (j + 1) ? "Images/join.gif" : "Images/joinbottom.gif") + "\"/></td>\n";
            resultaatStudentnamen += "\t\t\t\t\t\t<td>" + studentNamen.getFirstname() + " " + studentNamen.getLastname() + "</td>\n";
            resultaatStudentnamen += "\t\t\t\t\t</tr>\n";
            j++;
        }
        j = 0;
        for (Outgoing_teacher docentNamen : docentlijst.get(i - 1)) {
            resultaatDocentnamen += "<tr id=\"MeerInfoDocenten" + i + "\">\n";
            resultaatDocentnamen += "\t\t\t\t\t\t<td><img alt=\"\" name=\"lijn\" src=\"" + (instituten.size() != i ? "Images/line.gif" : "Images/empty.gif") + "\"/></td>\n";
            resultaatDocentnamen += "\t\t\t\t\t\t<td><img alt=\"\" name=\"lijn\" src=\"Images/empty.gif\"/></td>\n";
            resultaatDocentnamen += "\t\t\t\t\t\t<td><img alt=\"\" name=\"join\" src=\"" + (docentlijst.get(i - 1).size() != (j + 1) ? "Images/join.gif" : "Images/joinbottom.gif") + "\"/></td>\n";
            resultaatDocentnamen += "\t\t\t\t\t\t<td>" + docentNamen.getFirstname() + " " + docentNamen.getLastname() + "</td>\n";
            resultaatDocentnamen += "\t\t\t\t\t</tr>\n";
            j++;
        }
    %>
    <tr id="MeerInfoInstituut<%= i %>">
        <td><img alt="" name="lijn" src="${  urlLijnLong }"/></td>
        <td><img alt="" id="studenten<%= i %>" name="MeerInfoStudenten" src="Images/plus.gif" onclick="uitvouwen('MeerInfoStudenten<%= i %>', 'studenten<%= i %>')" style="cursor: pointer;"/></td>
        <td colspan="2">Reeds bezocht door <span><%=aantalStudenten%></span> student(en)</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <%=resultaatStudentnamen%>
    <tr id="MeerInfoInstituut<%= i %>">
        <td><img alt="" name="lijn" src="${  urlLijnLong }"/></td>
        <td><img alt="" id="docenten<%= i %>" name="MeerInfoDocenten" src="Images/plusbottom.gif" onclick="uitvouwen('MeerInfoDocenten<%= i %>','docenten<%= i %>')" style="cursor: pointer;"/></td>
        <td colspan="2">Reeds bezocht door <span><%=aantalDocenten%></span> docent(en)</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <%=resultaatDocentnamen%>
</table>
```

Comment: Get rid of this style of coding and migrateto JQuery. if you do so, use Accordion control if it's what you want.

Comment: it don't seams to me an onload problem it is probably an HTML problem or a CSS problem! you do better if post a code snippet of the <tr> structure instead of image...! @Jani - btw your responce have nothing to do with the OP question!

Comment: @aSeptik - thank you, the only problem then is that you can't use it in javascript because there ain't a .getElementByClass. It's HTML incorrect but i have no choise

Comment: see my responce! ;) hope it help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just for sake and for help of course! ;)

**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/ewajo3

your code should be just an example :

**HTML**

```
<tr id='caption_<%= i %>' class='tr_caption'>    
  <td>Lorem Ipsum Est <%= i %></td>    
  <td>         
    <a id='show_<%= i %>' href='javascript:;' onclick='show(this.id);'>+</a>
    <a id='hide_<%= i %>' href='javascript:;' onclick='hide(this.id);'>-</a>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr id='content_<%= i %>' class='tr_content'>
  <td colspan=2>The Brown Fox Jump Hover The Lazy Dog</td>
</tr>
```

**CSS**

```
.tr_content { display:none }
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function show(elm) {
   var id = 'content_' + elm.split('_')[1];
   document.getElementById(id).style.display='block';
}
function hide(elm) {
   var id = 'content_' + elm.split('_')[1];
   document.getElementById(id).style.display='none';
}
```

Comment: You make it al seem so easy, why didn't think of this. Thank you very extremely much.

Answer (score 0):

"Works perfectly" is a wide term, and in your case wrong.

Take ancient car for example.. 50 years old car that still drive (10 MPH) and still take you to the destination.... so you can say "the car is working perfectly". But it's slow and it break a lot.

Your code is the same. It's not efficient and can be improved greatly with little effort.

Anyway, your core logic is wrong as well, as IE simply does not support "collapse", see here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_visibility.asp

I will copy the relevant part:

> Note: No versions of Internet Explorer
>   (including IE8) support the property
>   values "inherit" or "collapse".

Bottom line, you better get back to the drawing board and find other way to achieve the design you want. jQuery is excellent choice, you have many many things available to you, just one search away.

Comment: OK, thank you. The only problem is that I haven't learned JQuery so I'm not allowed to use it (school and their rules). But I'll figure out another way with the tools I have

Comment: @Steve OK fair enough.. your best bet is trying to work with style.display instead of style.visibility - set the display to "none" in order to have it hidden, then have button to expand it back.

Comment: At our school it's always like this, I learn a new programming code, We get a project, I struggle with something because we can only use what we've learned, then we learn something new and I think to myself GOD what a waste of time, with this code I can easely make the previous thing.